# Wrong Form Submitted

Tags: html, forms, onsubmit

Please see the code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post" id="frmIdSave" name="frmNmSave" onsubmit="alert('Save');return false;">
<div>
 <input type=submit class="greyBttn" value="Save" id="btnIdSave" name=btnNameSave/>
 <input type="hidden" name="testsave" value="1" />
 </form>
 <form action="#" id="frmback" name="frmback" onsubmit="alert('Back');return false;">
 <input type="submit" class="greyBttn" value="Back" id="btnIdBack" name="btnNameBack"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="testback" value="1" />
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On IE11/Edge The back button is firing the onsubmit event on both forms on the page.

This is because the first form tag is outside the Div.

How can I get round this?

Thanks

Simon

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 3):

> This is because the first form tag is outside the Div.

Yes

> How can I get round this?

Write [valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). Move it inside the div.

Comment: My example code is hugely simplified. In reality between the form tag and that div there are loads of other divs and sections with fields in it for the form. This is just the bit at the bottom where you save the data. Note that this is only on IE11/Edge.

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved it with the code below.
It is worth noting though that when you submit using javascript, then the onsubmit event on the form is not called, so the complete solution for this would abstract any onsubmit code into a separate function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action=# method=post id=frmIdSave name=frmNmSave onsubmit="alert('Save');return false;">
<div>
<input type=submit class="greyBttn" value="Save" id=btnIdSave name=btnNameSave/>
<input type=hidden name=testsave value='1'/>
<input type=button class="greyBttn" onclick='document.getElementById("frmback").submit();' value="Back" id=btnIdBack name=btnNameBack/>

</div>
</form>

<form action=# id=frmback name=frmback onsubmit="alert('Back');return false;">
<input type=hidden name=testback value='1'/>
<input type=submit>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```